# Post projection sphere extent

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry

While browsing the source code for [Pixar's OpenSubdiv](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv) I came accross a short function that may be of interest to me, but that I don't understand:

```c
float OsdComputePostProjectionSphereExtent(vec3 center, float diameter)
{
    vec4 p = OsdProjectionMatrix() * vec4(center, 1.0);
    return abs(diameter * OsdProjectionMatrix()[1][1] / p.w);
}
```

([Github permalink](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv/blob/8ffa2b6566be10209529d7a0d1db02a0796b160c/opensubdiv/osd/glslPatchCommonTess.glsl#L92); I know that here `OsdProjectionMatrix()` simply returns the 4x4 projection matrix for the current frame.)

I believe this function takes as it's parameters the position of the center of a sphere in camera space and the radius of that sphere in camera space. From the function name, I gather that it then returns some "extent" of that sphere after projection to screen space with the projection matrix.

I've tried searching the web for "post projection sphere extent" in the hopes of perhaps finding an article or paper that provides more context, but have had no luck.

I know that spheres tend to project to ellipses. Does this function compute the length of the long axis of the projected ellipse, or perhaps an estimate of that length? If it is an estimate, is it a conservative estimate?

Or does it compute something else entirely?

I ask this here hoping to perhaps benefit from someone with a better understanding of the (linear) algebra involved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the projection of one of the sphere's principal axes (depending on what dimension `[1]` is either x or y). And assuming that the projection matrix does not have any other entry in the corresponding row.

Comment: @NicoSchertler If I'm understanding you correctly, it computes the width of an axis-aligned bounding box for the projected ellipse? And then, presumably, replacing `OsdProjectionMatrix()[1][1]` with `OsdProjectionMatrix()[0][0]` would compute the height of that axis-aligned bounding box?

Comment: It's not that sophisticated at all. It merely takes the extremal points of the sphere (top/bottom if `[1]` is the y-axis) and calculates the distance of their projections.